# Add mega account to cloud storage on es file explorer

Tags: cloud, es-file-explorer

I'm using es file pro version, I want to add mega account to cloud storage, the account addition section has "display as" so what should I fill in?

[image]

Comment: I would assume that this field allows you to name the account in your app (just used locally) so that you can add multiple Mega accounts without getting confused which folder is for which account.

Comment: I have tried to enter a name and still cannot log in